# What is this value/function called? (combinatorics/probabilities)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If you choose a random combination of 100 digits ranging from 0 to 9, then each such combination will also constitute a distribution distribution over the ten digits. Each such distribution will then also have it's polynomial coefficient, that is, the number of combinations with exactly the same distribution.
For example, a combination with 14 zirrows, 7 ones, 5 twos, 13 threes, 14 fours, 2 fives, 9 sixes, 23 sevens, 3 eights and  10 nines, will have the polynomial coefficient:
$$\frac{100!}{14! * 7! * 5! * 13! * 14! * 2! * 9! * 23! * 3! * 10!}  $$

Now, if you have a function that computes the percentage of all possible combinations (given a specific length and range of digits) which has a polynomial coefficient lower than or equal to a that of a specific other combination. What is such a function called?

Also, I would like to know if there is any term applied to the amount or percentage of combinations in which each digit is appearing more than a specified number of times (which is the same for all digits)?

Answer (score 1):

This coefficient is called [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: Both of the values I describe are called that? Is there any way of distinguishing between different types? I would like to know specifically what type of multinomial coefficient the value I first described is.